# Change the text in a subview dynamically

Tags: iphone, view, subview

I have created a 3 Subviews to MyView by creating new class inherits from UIView.
then i tried to change text in a particular subview say second sub view.
But its not updating.So how to do this...

**EDIT**

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
   CALayer *hitLater = [self layerForTouch:[touches anyObject]]; 
   if ([hitLater isKindOfClass:[Tile class]]) 
   {
      Tile *tile = (Tile *)hitLater; 
      heldTile = tile; 
      [tile draw2]; 
      [tile setNeedsDisplay]; 
   } 
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you show some code on how you are doing this, we could help you better!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a better answer show some code and how you add the text to your UIView subclasses etc.
But maybe you have to call setNeedsDisplay on your subviews so they get a redraw.

Comment: - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    
    CALayer *hitLater = [self layerForTouch:[touches anyObject]];
    
    if ([hitLater isKindOfClass:[Tile class]]) {
        Tile *tile = (Tile *)hitLater;
        heldTile = tile;
        [tile draw2];
        [tile setNeedsDisplay];
} }